# Wordpress - How to create a custom new page without new php file

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm creating a custom wordpress template. Usually i create files with the page name, for example if a have a page `about`, I create a file `page-about.php` and works fine. And I add acf fields to pages.

But if i want to create a new page with same structure of about pages without create a new php file? How can i do that?

Thank you.

Comment: what is your reasoning behind not creating a file such as `page-mypage.php`?

Comment: because if the client want to create a new page with some structure of others don't have to know create a php file. @Rushikumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question you stated you usually created your custom pages based on the page title, I would recommend you create a [custom page template](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/) that can be applied to as many pages as needed. You would need to create a .php file along the lines of custom-layout-about.php and put a php comment at the top to let wordpress know it's available.

```
<?php /* Template Name: custom page layout -- about */ ?>
```

Then apply your acf fields to target the page template.